# how to run java application on aws instance using command line

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I now have a java program and amazon instance provided with a key.. 
Used to run java on aws programmatically, but now all I need to do is, use this instance, powerful.. to run my java application, but how.?

Should I make my java program a .jar and upload on the instance?

And documents about the command needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You upload a file to your EC2 instance with `scp`:

`scp your.jar root@your.ec2:/tmp`

You run your file with `ssh`:

`ssh your.ec2 "java -jar /tmp/your.jar"`

All that can be easily automated since no passwords are required to execute scp or ssh, you'll just need to exchange certificates.

Or did you mean that you wanted to make Java program part of your **image**?

Comment: no.. i don't think so. it's just machine learning algorithm with super large training dataset that i need aws to handle. eclipse memory just failed. i was provided the key and root@ec2. is it possible to check the ec2..and existing folders on it..? does amazon has documents about the command lines? thx!

Comment: you can then ssh into your instance to analyse what happened : ```ssh -i <your key> ec2-user@<your ip address or hostname>```

Answer (score 0):

If your Java application is web based, I would encourage you to have a look at Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html

This service allows you to quickly deploy and manage applications to the cloud without worrying about the underlying infrastructure.

See more at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Java.html

Seb